# Android studio - Change firebase project for an android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I need to change the firebase project connected to my android app in development.

What I've done - I created a new firebase project, added my app, added the necessary sha 1 keys and downloaded the google_services.json file and replaced the content of the file with that in my android studio project.

The issue now is that the android project is still connected to my old firebase project.

What am I not doing right pls

Comment: I not understand your situation,do you want to connect a new android app to an existing firebase project?

Comment: I want to connect existing android app to a new firebase project

Comment: if you want new project then why did you replace content of the file with that in your  android studio project

Comment: Delete the google_service.json , then insert the google_service.json that just downloaded into same folder..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your effort. Rebuilding the project fixed the issue.